# How do you save the images generated by a pytorch generative adversarial network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I have followed this [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) tutorial on DCGAN to the letter, I managed to generate images successfully, however I cannot extract the generated images individually, they are only generated in the mosaic.

Is there a way to save the generated images one by one?

[image]

Comment: Well, skimming the tutorial, it looks like `img_list` contains the generated images...

Comment: is correct, however it has a form of (3, 530. 530) and I cannot extract the figures

Comment: That sounds like a 3-channel RGB image, so maybe do what the script does: `np.transpose(image, (1,2,0))` and then write that using e.g. imageio's imsave? Of course you can just `numpy.save` first and then load and process later.

Comment: The output image is expected to have a size of 64x64 since each training image has its size, saving that image does not correspond to any training image :(